# How can I write clean and simple code many if and else

Tags: java, if-statement

I just wrote this code. But I want to change this code simple and clean.

Do you have any feedback?

```
try {
        if (!videoFile.exists()) {
            videoFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            videoFile.delete();
            videoFile.createNewFile();
        }
        if (!cnFile.exists()) {
            cnFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            cnFile.delete();
            cnFile.createNewFile();
        }
        if (!enFile.exists()) {
            enFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            enFile.delete();
            enFile.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is type of `videoFile`, `cnFile`, `enFile`? If they are of same super type, you can create a method to accept superType, and then do if and else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both branches of the if/else, you create the file.  Move it out of the if statement

```
    if (videoFile.exists())
        videoFile.delete();
    videoFile.createNewFile();

    if (cnFile.exists())
        cnFile.delete();
    cnFile.createNewFile();

    if (enFile.exists())
        enFile.delete();
    enFile.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a private method:

```
private void createFile(File file) {  // if not File, then whatever type you need
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    } else {
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

Then call it multiple times:

```
try {

    createFile(videoFile);
    createFile(cnFile);
    createFile(enFile);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting the file if exists,  You just delete the file always without checking if the file exists or not and create the new file.

```
videoFile.delete();
videoFile.createNewFile();

cnFile.delete();
cnFile.createNewFile();

enFile.delete();
enFile.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is not strictly needed as `File.delete` does not throw an exception if the file doesn't exist, returning `false` instead (and it seems you are not interested in that result).
And iterating over a file list can even simplify it further:

```
File[] files = new File[]{videoFile, cnFile, enFile};
for(File f: files) {
    f.delete();
    f.createNewFile();
}
```